# How to fix an error in a for loop. Pascal

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, pascal

I wrote a programm, but there is an error that i can't understand.

Error: main.pas(23,11) Fatal: Syntax error, ")" expected but "ordinal const" found

```
program Hello; <-- 10 line
var 

x : integer;
y : integer;


begin


for x := 0 to 120 do

    begin
                                <-- error line
        if ( x % 5 = 0 ) then
            writeln (x);
    
    end;

  
end. <-- 30 line
```

Comment: `x % 5 = 0` is the error. You probably want to use the modulo operator. `%` is the modulo operator in c and other languages. In pascal the modulo operator is `mod`. That is `x mod 5 = 0`.

Comment: @LURD Thanks, it worked. You can write it in answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x % 5 = 0` is the error.

You probably want to use the modulo operator.

`%` is the modulo operator in c and other languages. In pascal the modulo operator is `mod`.

The correct statement would then be:

```
if (x mod 5 = 0) then WriteLn(x);
```